# How to run a server in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, server

How to run a server in python?
I already have tried:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
python -m HTTPServer
```

but its says to me:

```
invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to run those lines in a python interpreter? You need to run that from the command line. Also, for Python 3, it's `python -m http.server` now.

Comment: See https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use this command in cmd or terminal

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer <port_number>    # Python 2.x
```

Python 3.x

```
python3 -m http.server     # Python 3x
```

By default, this will run the contents of the directory on a local web server, on port `8000`. You can go to this server by going to the URL `localhost:8000` in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a remote access program that uses the Socket module. If you want to copy the code, that's fine. EDIT: You will need to run it using a cmd file like this: "python (filename).py." After that, you will need to add the line "pause"

```
#SERVER
import os
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080
s.bind((host, port))
print("Server started at: ", host)
s.listen(1)
conn,addr = s.accept()
print(addr, "connected")


#CLIENT
import os
import socket

s = socket.socket()
port = 8080
host = "YOUR DESKTOP ID" (Your server should say it. I.E. "Server started at: (Desktop-123456)")
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a cmd file to run the python script, add a while 1 loop at the bottom of the code for both of the files.

while 1: